# Java web call over https failing due to handshake_failure

Tags: java, security, ssl, jce, jsse

I am calling a service over https and it is failing with handshake_failure error. Not able to understand the reason. I have the correct server certificate and that is placed in my cacerts file. I have obtained following JSSE trace.

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(5000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1507199237 bytes = { 28, 231, 211, 145, 72, 123, 216, 22, 202, 150, 123, 212, 202, 60, 168, 238, 86, 75, 34, 107, 197, 190, 198, 222, 41, 94, 201, 249 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 163
0000: 01 00 00 9F 03 03 5A D6   09 05 1C E7 D3 91 48 7B  ......Z.......H.
0010: D8 16 CA 96 7B D4 CA 3C   A8 EE 56 4B 22 6B C5 BE  .......<..VK"k..
0020: C6 DE 29 5E C9 F9 00 00   48 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  ..)^....H.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0   03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00  2...............
0070: FF 01 00 00 2E 00 0A 00   08 00 06 00 17 00 18 00  ................
0080: 19 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00   0D 00 18 00 16 06 03 06  ................
0090: 01 05 03 05 01 04 03 04   01 03 03 03 01 02 03 02  ................
00A0: 01 02 02                                           ...
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 163
[Raw write]: length = 168
0000: 16 03 03 00 A3 01 00 00   9F 03 03 5A D6 09 05 1C  ...........Z....
0010: E7 D3 91 48 7B D8 16 CA   96 7B D4 CA 3C A8 EE 56  ...H........<..V
0020: 4B 22 6B C5 BE C6 DE 29   5E C9 F9 00 00 48 C0 24  K"k....)^....H.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 08   C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D  ...3.2..........
0070: 00 16 00 13 00 FF 01 00   00 2E 00 0A 00 08 00 06  ................
0080: 00 17 00 18 00 19 00 0B   00 02 01 00 00 0D 00 18  ................
0090: 00 16 06 03 06 01 05 03   05 01 04 03 04 01 03 03  ................
00A0: 03 01 02 03 02 01 02 02                            ........
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: handshake_failure has many possible causes. Best is to check the server log(s) and see what it says the problem is. Otherwise you have to start guessing; it almost certainly isn't version or ciphersuites, so my first guess would be lack of SNI; you can test that using `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port` with and without `-servername $host`.

Comment: What do I have to specify in servername option? openssl s_client --help says "Set TLS extension servername in ClientHello". I dind't get that

Comment: SNI (Server Name Indication) is indeed an extension in ClientHello that is set by this option. For HTTPS it should be the name of the host in your (possibly notional) URL, normally the same as the host you connect to, but if you connect to a nonstandard port like `example.com:8443` then SNI is `example.com` not `example.com:8443`. (Below 1.1.0 `-help` actually says `host` but the new table-based parser doesn't.)